# In Castle Windsor how can I override a type registered with FromThisAssembly()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I'm trying to build a plugin architecture for asp.net MVC which would allow Controllers to be overriden.

On my App_Start() I have this:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
   new WindsorControllerFactory(container));
```

And a bit before an installer for all Controllers inside the Assembly:

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

This is based on the [Windsor Tutorial](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-two-plugging-Windsor-in.ashx?HL=ikernel).

Now, on my plugin or module, I would like to register new Controllers and be able to override specific controllers already registered on the base MVC application.

The problem is, there isn't a way to call .Overridable() or .IsDefault() when using the registration method above. How could I do something like this:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) {
            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().
            BasedOn<IController>().
            LifestyleTransient().
            IsDefault()); // This does not compile.
```

In essence, how to override something registered by type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a convention registration like `Classes`, you cannot call unitary methods like `SetDefault` directly; that wouldn't make sense since you're returning a collection of elements, all of which cannot be the default one. (To be more precise, the convention lets you declare descriptions of the components that interest you; the type used is a `BasedOnDescriptor`. The `IsDefault` method exists on the `ComponentRegistration` class)

However it is possible to call a `Configure` method (and its variations `ConfigureIf` and `ConfigureFor`) that lets you call unitary methods on a component. So you could call the `IsDefault` using the `Configure` method

```
var regs = Classes
           .FromThisAssembly()
           .Pick()
           .WithServiceAllInterfaces(); // dummy registration
regs.Configure(c => c.IsDefault());
```

Of course you would need to define how the default component is determined. For example if the default component name contains the word `"default"` you may use the `ConfigureIf` method:

```
regs.ConfigureIf(component => component.Name.ToLower().Contains("default"), 
                          component => component.IsDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windsor, the first registration wins, so subsequent registrations of a service won't override the initial registration.

So what you will want to do is perform your most specific registrations first, *then* do the more general, convention-based auto-registrations.

See section "**In Windsor first one wins**" on [this](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx) page.

Comment: But is there a way to override this behaviour?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what would be in your plug-in?  Maybe modify your question to show the whole lifecycle of initial state, then adding plugins later?

Comment: The plugin would contain Controllers and Views to augment the base MVC app.